# All the wordpress links points to localhost/dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress install at localhost. I was working on my website when i suddenly notice that all the links on my website starts pointing at localhost/dashboard. Each time I visit my website and click on any link it sends me to localhost/dashboard. But the link which appears at the bottom left corner in google chrome appears to be right.
Is there any way to fix this

Comment: Can you check htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Try to update `permalinks`. Go `wp-admin>settings>permalinks` and press "Save changes" button

Answer (score 0):

in reality , you will not want your WordPress permalinks configured as localhost because when other client request web site files from your WordPress Apache web server , WordPress will direct their traffic to load their own loacalhost which mean they will failed load css or js file from your web server and get broken image\style\web site .

[image]

configure this option inside your wordpress web site will make sure all received web request proper direct to a right wordpress server , use a valid public IP or DNS name or private static IP rather then localhost

[image]